# extract phone number from HTML

Tags: php, curl, xpath

I want to pull phone number from a website, but in the end I got error.

```
Error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing.php on line 15
```

my code is as below:

```
$ch=curl_init("http://www.mudah.my/LG+G+Pro+2+D838+16GB+5+9in+2+26GHz+3GB+RAM+NEW+SET-30256077.htm");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$cl = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($cl);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$phoneNo = $xpath->query("//div[@class='contact-phoneno']/text()");

$phone = $phoneNo->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $phone;
```

Comment: you should first check if `item(0)` exists via `$phoneNo->length > 0` before you try to access `nodeValue`

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing.php on line 19

I got this error. My code -> $phone = $phoneNo->item(0)->length;

Comment: No. `if ($phoneNo->length > 0) { $phone = $phoneNo->item(0)->nodeValue; }`

Comment: if ($phoneNo->length > 0) { $phone = $phoneNo->item(0)->nodeValue;
print_r($phone); }


@SBH This gives me no error, but totally blank page. Nothing come out

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
$phoneNo = $xpath->query("//div[@class='contact-phoneno']");
$phone = $phoneNo->item(0)->textContent;
```

I obtain: `013611xxxx`

Comment: thank you so much, at least I got some improvement on it.thanks..hope that I can retrieve the full phone number as soon as possible

Comment: Sorry,again, You know how to get the full phone number? Because both of the code have the same name(//div[@class='contact-phoneno']).

Comment: You need to give more information about your XML so that somebody can give you the final answer.

Comment: I need to get the full phone number on the page for my project evaluation purpose, the page is on the first line of the code.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you want. '013611xxxx' is not the **full** phone number ?